# how to use react-dates in reactjs properly

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';



import {DateRangePicker, SingleDatePicker, DayPickerRangeController} from 'react-dates';
import 'react-dates/lib/css/_datepicker.css';

class Clients extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focusedInput: '',
      startDate: '',
      endDate: ''
    };
    this.onDatesChange = this.onDatesChange.bind(this)
    this.onFocusChange = this.onFocusChange.bind(this)
  }
  onDatesChange({startDate, endDate}) {

    this.setState({startDate, endDate});
  }

  onFocusChange(focusedInput) {
    this.setState({focusedInput});
  }

  render() {
    const {focusedInput, startDate, endDate} = this.state;

    return (<div className="animated fadeIn">


      <div>
        <DateRangePicker
          onDatesChange={this.onDatesChange} 
          onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
          focusedInput={focusedInput}
          startDate={startDate}
           endDate={endDate}/></div>

    </div>);
  }
}

export default Clients;
```

the errors are :
arning: Failed prop type: Invalid input type: `startDate` of type `string` supplied to `DayPickerRangeController`, expected `object`.
    in DayPickerRangeController (created by DateRangePicker)
    in DateRangePicker (created by withStyles(DateRangePicker))
    in withStyles(DateRangePicker) (created by Clients)
    in div (created by Clients)
    in div (created by Clients)
    in Clients (created by Route)
    in Route (created by Full)
    in Switch (created by Full)
    in div (created by Container)
    in Container (created by Full)
    in main (created by Full)
    in div (created by Full)
    in div (created by Full)
    in Full (created by Route)
    in Route
    in Switch
    in Router (created by HashRouter)
    in HashRouter

this happens when i click on startdate to pick a date any help ?

Comment: try to use moment library, passing a new moment object to react-dates , moment(). Then you can asign the start date you need using moment.

Comment: how should i use react-moments with daterangepicker ?

Comment: install moment with npm or yarn ( npm i moment --save), import moment on your component, and render react-dates with startDate={moment()}.

Comment: it is now working thank you

Comment: Ok I'll put it like an answer, please validate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved using `moment` library to set startDate

installing moment:

```
 npm i moment --save
 yarn add moment
```

import moment at your component:

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

set startDate at react-dates with a moment object

```
startDate={moment()}
```

Comment: another question  :

Comment: I need to have a key the use it when I change the date 
let's say I have multiple date range pickers
how could I find which is what I have changed 
something like that 
 onDatesChange({startDate, endDate , Key}) {

    this.setState({startDate, endDate});
  }